# loop through multiple questions each with a condition in Python

Tags: python

I am creating a program where you will have to loop through multiple questions each with a condition. If user input for the question does not meet the requirement, it will print out the error and prompt user to re-enter. Else, it will continue with the next question. And not only prompting user to re-enter after all 3 questions are answered.

This it the output I am getting now:

```
while True:
    amount = int(input("Enter amount: "))
    rate = int(input("Enter rate: "))
    year = float(input("Enter year: "))

    
    if amount<4000:
        print("Invalid amount")
        continue
    
    elif rate<0:
        print("invalid rate") 
        continue
    
    elif year<0:
        print("invalid year")
    break
```

Output:

```
Enter amount: 1
Enter rate: 3
Enter year: 4
Invalid amount
Enter amount:
```

Expected output:

```
Enter amount: 4
Invalid amount
Enter amount:
```

Comment: And what is the problem ? :)

Comment: There seems no problem in your code, it works fine. please explain in detail your query

Comment: @andymeissner  just edited my post of the expected outcome. hope it is clearer. Basically I want the error to show once the user has made the wrong input and not when all question is asked.

Comment: See my answer for a solution to that

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what are you trying to achieve, but I think you want this:

```py
while True:
    amount = int(input("Enter amount: "))
    if amount < 4000:
        print("Invalid amount")
        continue
    break

while True:
    rate = int(input("Enter rate: "))
    if rate < 0:
        print("invalid rate") 
        continue
    break

while True:
    year = float(input("Enter year: "))
    if year < 0:
        print("invalid year")
        continue
    break
```

This will only ask to re-enter the invalid values.

Answer (score 0):

Another more reusable method would be:

```
def loop_user_input(input_name, meets_condition):
    while True:
        value = int(input(f"Enter {input_name}: "))
        if not meets_condition(value):
            print(f"Invalid {input_name}")
        else:
            return value

loop_user_input('amount', lambda val: val < 4000)
loop_user_input('rate', lambda val: val < 0)
loop_user_input('year', lambda val: val < 0)
```

Here you have a loop that only returns when the input value meets the condition, that you pass in. I recommend you check your conditions, because a year normally shouldn't be negative (rate < 0). Also your solution throws an exception, if the user enters something else then an int. Maybe add a `try-catch` to your solution:

```
    try:
        value = int(input(f"Enter {input_name}: "))
    except:
        print(f"Invalid {input_name}")
        continue
```